# sorting list by length of sublist

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list with sublist,

```
mylist = [['loan', 'finance'], ['dealer', 'dealers', 'dealership'], ['Data entry', 'data entry', 'enter data']]
```

I want to sort by using the length of the sublist, so that the output is expected as

```
reqlist = [['dealer', 'dealers', 'dealership'], ['Data entry', 'data entry', 'enter data'], ['loan', 'finance']]
```

I was trying to use [sorting](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) function

```
 def take(element): 
    return len(element)
 reqlist = sorted(reqlist, key = take)
```

I tried list.sort

```
 mylist.sort(key=len)
```

it doesnt work and output 'reqlist' is not as expected and is same as 'mylist'. Any help required.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Did your solution not give you the results you wanted? What did it output vs what did you want it to output?

Comment: is `reqlist = sorted(data, key=take, reverse=True)` what you are looking for? Because otherwise, it seems to be working

Comment: edit made, please check. the output is not as expected.

Comment: as by @Ev.Kounis comment: the sorting works just fine, sorting for length 2,3,3. But you want reverse sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reqlist = sorted(mylist, key=len, reverse=True)
```